# Which PowerShell cmdlets from MS support -UseTransaction

Tags: powershell, transactions

Other than registry and SQL server related commands, are there any other Microsoft-provided PowerShell commands that support transaction?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Get-Command | 
where {$_.parameters.UseTransaction} |
select name
```

Comment: I like this method, and can use it for researching other parameters.

Answer (score 4):

PowerShell transactions are only supported (currently) by the Registry provider.

```
Get-PSProvider | Where Capabilities -Like *Transactions*
```

So the commands that @mjolinor's answer provides will only support transactions if the "item" in question is a registry item.